# Censoring/pixelizing sensitive information with MS Paint?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I need to post a screenshot for a bug report or superuser/stackoverflow question, that contains sensitive information, and have only MS Paint available at the PC at hand.

Since layout issues are part of the bug report, text should remain readable.

(This is posted as Q&A).

Answer (score 1):

1. First, import the screenshot into MS-Paint; The screenshot can be easily taken by using the <kbd>PrScr</kbd> button (German: <kbd>Druck</kbd>), or combined with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to take a screenshot of only the current window.
2. Open MS Paint and paste it with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>. Optionally, first resize the empty page to a size smaller than the expected screenshot before pasting; When pasting the image resizes to fit the pasted image. (*Home > Image > Resize*, and set it e.g. to "1%"). [image]
3. After pasting select the part you want to pixelate, and use the resize tool to shrink the selected content and resize it back to full-size, which will pixelate it. E.g. in order to get a 4-pixel pixelation, resize to 25% and then, without changing the selection, to 400%. [image]